# Will Web Apps have an RSS feed?

Tags: support, feature-request

I'd like an RSS feed to remind me to visit the site.  Does something like this exist already?

I know they'd be huge, but my first idea is one for each one of the tabs: "New" (perhaps compliled daily), "Hot"(also daily), "Week", "Month".  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can find RSS feeds at the bottom of the page for whatever tab you are looking for. Also, there should be an RSS icon in the address bar, if you are using firefox, opera, or IE.

Comment: Ah, missed it because it's not orange (I'm using Chrome).  Thanks!

Comment: @Sarah Nagy Yeah, it would be nice if chrome followed suit and added the little icon.